# asp.net wizard reload same step twice

Tags: asp.net

I have a asp.net wizard control. I'm getting user input in step 3 using datagrid having some textboxes. The grid also has lebels which is filled with some related information. In Fourth step, i will process the inputs and create some configurations.

Now i need to show a summary of information which includes input information (textbox and label) after step 3 and before step 4. I can create a new wizard step for summary and show all this informtions, but i have to create a similar kind of datagrid/(or some other way) by filling all the information from step 3. Instead i can just reuse the step 3 datagrid added with some labels along with the textbox and show it only during summary step. But in order to do that i have to violate the wizard concept like cancel the current step (e.cancel = true) during the next button click and have some flag to reload that same step again, which i don't feel as a proper way.

Do you guys a better way to acheive this? Sorry if the question is confusing, i can add more information based on the queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to incorporate it into your current wizard, you need to handle the `ActiveStepChanged` event manually, and use the wizard history to determine which step should be loaded.

This will get you the last step visited:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets the last wizard step visited.
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
private WizardStep GetLastStepVisited()
{
    //initialize a wizard step and default it to null
    WizardStep previousStep = null;

    //get the wizard navigation history and set the previous step to the first item
    var wizardHistoryList = (ArrayList)wzServiceOrder.GetHistory();
    if (wizardHistoryList.Count > 0)
        previousStep = (WizardStep)wizardHistoryList[0];

    //return the previous step
    return previousStep;
}
```

Here's some logic I wrote a while ago that's similar to what you're trying to do:

```
/// <summary>
/// Navigates the wizard to the appropriate step depending on certain conditions.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="currentStep">The active wizard step.</param>
private void NavigateToNextStep(WizardStepBase currentStep)
{
    //get the wizard navigation history and cast the collection as an array list 
    var wizardHistoryList = (ArrayList)wzServiceOrder.GetHistory();

    if (wizardHistoryList.Count > 0)
    {
        var previousStep = wizardHistoryList[0] as WizardStep;
        if (previousStep != null)
        {
            //determine which direction the wizard is moving so we can navigate to the correct step
            var stepForward = wzServiceOrder.WizardSteps.IndexOf(previousStep) < wzServiceOrder.WizardSteps.IndexOf(currentStep);

            if (currentStep == wsViewRecentWorkOrders)
            {
                //if there are no work orders for this site then skip the recent work orders step
                if (grdWorkOrders.Items.Count == 0)
                    wzServiceOrder.MoveTo(stepForward ? wsServiceDetail : wsSiteInformation);
            }
            else if (currentStep == wsExtensionDates)
            {
                //if no work order is selected then bypass the extension setup step
                if (grdWorkOrders.SelectedItems.Count == 0)
                    wzServiceOrder.MoveTo(stepForward ? wsServiceDetail : wsViewRecentWorkOrders);
            }
            else if (currentStep == wsSchedule)
            {
                //if a work order is selected then bypass the scheduling step
                if (grdWorkOrders.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
                    wzServiceOrder.MoveTo(stepForward ? wsServicePreview : wsServiceDetail);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.. looks like i have to handle everything manually.. I' little bit hesitant to do this approach, because for me rest of the steps are and are intact, but only for this simple step do i have to change and  handle everything manually?

Comment: It doesn't need to be entirely manual. The method above is just for *when* you need branching, otherwise just let it operate normally. My example looks complex because of all the branching that was needed for that functionality.